# Does Android APIs have compatibilty for its old versions?

Tags: android, api, sdk

I'm downloading Android SDK , and want to know if  Android's APIs has compatibility with its 
Previous versions ?  i.e. if i installed Android API 16 can I use the application on
Android 4.0 (API 14) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run older API versions on newer systems, but not vice-versa. For example Android 4.0 can run programs made for Android 2.3.3, but Android 2.3.3 can't run Android 4.0 programs.

Comment: Then if i'm to choose an API version to download from  1.5 to 4.1.2
which one is recommended ???

Comment: You should take a look at the market distribution. If you build an app for API 4.1 only 10-20% of mobile phones can run your app, while an app for 2.3.3 can be ran on 70% of mobile phones. There is more info on that topic here : http://developer.android.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a minimum sdk level in your android manifest. Every version from this upwards supports the app. You can only use classes and language elements that are supported by this specified version.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the following in your manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

This means: 
1) your app won't run on any Android whose version < 8. 
Android OS whose version < 8 will not let your app be installed.

2) Your app is using Android API as of Android version 15. 
In your code you can, however, check the Android version (using [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)) and if it is < 15 then do not run certain code. 
This is often done so the app can use newer features if run on newer Android versions yet it can run on older versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not all components are backwards compatible, but for backwards stuff, look at the following

I found the most useful library out there for making an android app backwards compatible.

Its called Actionbarsherlock, it gives you all android 4.1+ functionality all the way back to 2.1 (what i am developing as a min version)

Its fairly simple to use, very well explained on their website:
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Enjoy